# Allow a question to be opened after it is closed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, closed-questions, bookmarks

I propose that it should be possible for closed questions to be opened/unclosed if there us sufficient interest (up-votes or favorite). This would mean that the masses could decide that although Jeff ;) thinks the question should be closed because it's of topic, if enough people (I have no idea how many) think they like the question or want to see answers to it, they could vote for it to be opened.

Comment: My bad for not RTFM-ing. soz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the design already. FAQ:

```
15       Vote up
15       Flag offensive
50       Leave comments
100      Vote down (costs 1 rep), edit community wiki posts
200      Reduced advertising
250      Vote to close or open your questions, create new tags
500      Retag questions
2000     Edit other people's posts
3000     Vote to close any questions
10000    Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
```

Assuming you want to vote to (re)open your own question, being at 848 (nice) can already do this.

OTOH on meta, I cannot vote to close your question with 138 rep (until I reach 3000 rep).

Comment: this is a good point, the faq could be made more clear here. Will fix.

Comment: @Jeff: Put 'or reopen' on the 3000 line too

Answer (score 2):

This already happens. People can vote to reopen a question.

Comment: With high enough rep, but not just form the community voting the question up or favorite-ing it.